# What is the best method for parsing XML in ASP.NET 3.5/C#?

Tags: xml, asp.net-3.5

What is the best method for parsing XML in ASP.NET 3.5/C#?

Comment: A very subjective question. Different methods are best for different scenarios. I suggest you rephrase it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Reading XML documents using LINQ to XML](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1524) and [XML Made Easy with LINQ to XML](http://www.i-think22.net/archives/2009/02/25/xml-made-easy-with-linq-to-xml/)

Answer (score 1):

With Linq to XML, I can do in one line what would have taken 10 in with System.XML. Granted it is a longer line.